# Facing this error while trying to run react-native application on android emulator->ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, cmakelists-options

dependencies with version used in myProject are :
gradle : 8.0.1
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.4.1", // I think this is causing the issue

Task :react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

CMake Warning in CMakeLists.txt:
The object file directory

```
  C:/Users/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/Debug/c5f614v4/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/reanimated.dir/./

has 198 characters.  The maximum full path to an object file is 250
characters (see CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX).  Object file

  C_/Users/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/Common/cpp/NativeModules/NativeReanimatedModule.cpp.o

cannot be safely placed under this directory.  The build may not work
correctly.
```

I have deleted node_modules and installed it with npm install --force, also try to run project with npm start -- --reset-cache

Answer (score 1):

> you can use different version of react-native-reanimated

```
"react-native-reanimated": "2.2.4",
```

> also set the babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

> in iOS podfile write this line as well

```
pod 'RNReanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your response it solved my issue for now. I had downgraded reanimated version. what to do if i wanted to use the version i had specified in my project

Answer (score 0):

```
    module.exports = {
     presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
     plugins: [[
     'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
     ]],
    }
```

Add react-native-reanimated in plugin, File name: babel.config.js